# How do I use lxml to interact with the page and pull up a menu to be scraped?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, lxml

For reference, [this is the page that I will use as an example. It is the one that best demonstrates what I am trying to accomplish.](https://www.ebay.com/b/Component-Solenoids/181878/bn_7563749) If you look at the page, there is a brands banner at the top of the screen. In the top right hand corner, there is a see all button which pulls up a menu. The data from this menu is not in the html, it is generated by the click of that button. Is there any way to have lxml perform the action of clicking that button and pulling up that menu?

I took a look at the network log. There does not appear to me that there is any file or url in there that would contain the data from that menu. I believe selenium does have this functionality, but I would prefer to not have to use only lxml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lxml is a parser, so it cannot click button elements on the page. Unfortunately, using a tool like Selenium is what you need to do to accomplish this.

I know you mentioned looking at the network log. Usually in these cases it is best to try to find the endpoint and issue the request directly, but if you tried and can't find the request then use Selenium.

Comment: I was afraid that would be the case. Oh well then, time to learn selenium.